# Capacitance of Parallel Plates

Tags: charge, capacitance, conventions

For Parallel Plate Capacitors, I was wondering why, in the derivation, they set charge to $Q$, when there is a net charge of zero? I know it wouldn't be very helpful to use zero, but if the definition is amount of charge being able to be store, wouldn't using something like $2Q$ make more sense? Or is it because there really only is $Q$ charge, the $+Q$ being absence of charge?

Comment: It is just a convention.  We define the charge $Q$ to be the charge on one of the plates and go from there.  You can define it differently, but the physical result must be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering why, in the derivation, they set charge to Q... but if the definition is amount of charge being able to be store

$Q$ is the charge *separated*, not stored.  A charged capacitor is not electrically charged any more than a charged battery is.  Rather, a charged capacitor has stored *energy*.

To charge a parallel plate capacitor, electric charge is 'pumped' from one plate to the other via an external circuit.

This leaves one plate with electric charge $-Q$ and the other with electric charge $+Q$.  While each plate is electrically charged, the capacitor is electrically neutral.

Work must be done by the external circuit in this process and the work done by the circuit equals the energy stored in the capacitor which is proportional to $Q^2$.

See, for example, this article at [hyperphysics:  Storing Energy in a Capacitor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng2.html).

---

> But wiki says capacitance is the ability of a body to store charge...

You must distinguish between *capacitance* and *capacitor*; these are very different notions.

Indeed an *isolated* conductor has an associated capacitance which is simply the ratio of the charge on the conductor and the potential of the conductor (relative to infinity).

But a *capacitor* consists of *two* conductors where the capacitance *between* the two conductors is defined as the ratio of the amount of charge *separated* and the voltage difference between the two conductors.  Typically, this capacitance is *far* larger than the capacitance of the individual conductors.

Comment: But wiki says capacitance is the ability of a body to *store* charge...

Comment: Actually then, in general, if you have two different surfaces with different charge-what is the capacitance dependent on? Because now one thing is holding some charge, while the other holds a different charge, how do you know how much charge it is effectively holding?

Comment: @Anthony, the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By charge on capacitor, we (generally) mean the magnitude of charge on one of the plates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful of your Gaussian surface. If you include both charges (from both plates) then your Gaussian surface is outside of the parallel plate capacitor and the electric field is indeed zero because there is zero net charge when encapsulating the parallel plates with your Gaussian surface. However, if you place one part side of your Gaussian surface inside the parallel plates (and through the one of them) then you will find that there is a electric field in a certain direction on both the inside and outside. Do the same with the other plate and you will find that on the outside of the capacitor the electric fields cancel and on the inside of the capacitor they add (they are in same direction).

Not sure what you mean by: because there really only is $Q$ charge, the $+Q$ being an absence of charge...